# How do you clear the console screen in C?

Tags: c, windows, console, console-application

Is there a "proper" way to clear the console window in C, besides using `system("cls")`?

Comment: http://www.cplusplus.com/forum/articles/10515/ contains some codes. Although not portable for both Windows and POSIX systems it can be useful for anyone reading this question in future.

Comment: Also here http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o/

Comment: Nobody has mentioned the standard ASCII control FF (form feed) which ejects a page on printers or printing terminals (such as vt100).

Answer (score 31, accepted):

Well, C doesn't understand the concept of screen. So any code would fail to be portable. Maybe take a look at [conio.h](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) or
[curses](http://wikipedia.org/wiki/Curses_(programming_library)), according to your needs?

Portability is an issue, no matter what library is used.

Comment: I +1'd you before reading your line about conio.h. Note that, too, is highly non-portable.

Comment: I'm not sure about conio.h, but it looks like curses takes care of the GUI in a more comprehensive way than I was initially imagining.  I'll have to look into this. Thanks for the suggestion!

Answer (score 44):

```
printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J");
```

This function will work on ANSI terminals, demands POSIX. I assume there is a version that might also work on window's console, since it also supports ANSI escape sequences.

```
#include <unistd.h>

void clearScreen()
{
  const char *CLEAR_SCREEN_ANSI = "\e[1;1H\e[2J";
  write(STDOUT_FILENO, CLEAR_SCREEN_ANSI, 12);
}
```

There are some other
[alternatives](http://www.cplusplus.com/articles/4z18T05o), some of which don't move the cursor to {1,1}.

Comment: Just to let you know, FWIW, this sequence as is didn't work for me in a windows cmd.exe console.

Comment: @anon : This if for UNIX. Do you do the answer for DOS?

Comment: How does it demand POSIX? I don't believe those escape sequences are specified by the POSIX standard.

Comment: That doesn't work for me. What *does* work for me, though, is plain old `"\e[2J"`. I know it's been like four years, but... Care to explain the difference? Or what the `"\e[1;1H"` is supposed to do?

Comment: This code seems to work fine on Windows' CMD, at least in Win10.

Comment: Using [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1348624/1429450) I didn't get ISO compatibility errors: `\033[2J\033[1;1H`

Comment: Windows' command prompt (Windows 98 through Windows 7) does not support ANSI escapes. It seems that they do in Windows 10 and so presumably Windows 8 as noted by QPaysTaxes.

Comment: Nit: Don't use `printf(string);`, use `puts(string);` instead. The former may have UB if `string` contains a percent sign (even though that is not the case here, I recommend making it a habit).

Comment: Why does that regex work? Can someone please post a link that explains this?

Comment: `\033[x;yH` will re-position the cursor to row `x`, column `y`. If `x` is 1, it can may be omitted: `\033[;yH`. https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ANSI_escape_code#Terminal_output_sequences

Answer (score 28):

For portability, try this:

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#include <conio.h>
#else
#include <stdio.h>
#define clrscr() printf("\e[1;1H\e[2J")
#endif
```

Then simply call `clrscr()`. On Windows, it will use `conio.h`'s `clrscr()`, and on Linux, it will use ANSI escape codes.

If you *really* want to do it "properly", you can eliminate the middlemen (`conio`, `printf`, etc.) and do it with just the low-level system tools (prepare for a massive code-dump):

```
#ifdef _WIN32
#define WIN32_LEAN_AND_MEAN
#include <windows.h>

void ClearScreen()
{
  HANDLE                     hStdOut;
  CONSOLE_SCREEN_BUFFER_INFO csbi;
  DWORD                      count;
  DWORD                      cellCount;
  COORD                      homeCoords = { 0, 0 };

  hStdOut = GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE );
  if (hStdOut == INVALID_HANDLE_VALUE) return;

  /* Get the number of cells in the current buffer */
  if (!GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo( hStdOut, &csbi )) return;
  cellCount = csbi.dwSize.X *csbi.dwSize.Y;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with spaces */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputCharacter(
    hStdOut,
    (TCHAR) ' ',
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

  /* Fill the entire buffer with the current colors and attributes */
  if (!FillConsoleOutputAttribute(
    hStdOut,
    csbi.wAttributes,
    cellCount,
    homeCoords,
    &count
    )) return;

  /* Move the cursor home */
  SetConsoleCursorPosition( hStdOut, homeCoords );
}

#else // !_WIN32
#include <unistd.h>
#include <term.h>

void ClearScreen()
{
  if (!cur_term)
  {
     int result;
     setupterm( NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, &result );
     if (result <= 0) return;
  }

   putp( tigetstr( "clear" ) );
}
#endif
```

Comment: Actually this is really nice. +1 for pointing the "portable" way using ANSI escapes with the horrible but useful clrscr() from conio.h.

Comment: Just for saying: clrscr() is not available on conio.h implementation of mingw compiler

Answer (score 20):

A workaround tested on Windows(cmd.exe), Linux(Bash and zsh) and OS X(zsh):

```
#include <stdlib.h>

void clrscr()
{
    system("@cls||clear");
}
```

Comment: 1- Its monstruous; 2- The OP explicitly asked not to use it; 3- OP is asking for C language command, and `system` calls commands for other languages (said, bash, zsh, batch, etc.). Still +1 to try to make it portable. (I've tested on debian/linux and win7, even inverting the arguments. No need the @ also, because the command will not be on the screen after run)

Answer (score 15):

Using macros you can check if you're on Windows, Linux, Mac or Unix, and call the respective function depending on the current platform. Something as follows:

```
void clear(){
    #if defined(__linux__) || defined(__unix__) || defined(__APPLE__)
        system("clear");
    #endif

    #if defined(_WIN32) || defined(_WIN64)
        system("cls");
    #endif
}
```

Comment: `_WIN32` will be defined on Windows even if you build for 64-bit.

Answer (score 9):

Since you mention `cls`, it sounds like you are referring to windows.  If so, then [this KB item](http://support.microsoft.com/kb/99261) has the code that will do it.  I just tried it, and it worked when I called it with the following code:

```
cls( GetStdHandle( STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE ));
```

Comment: +1 although i didnt ask, but this can be quite useful. And what can be done on unix to 'clear'?

Comment: @nvl:  I only have windows machines at home, and takes about 15 usernames and passwords to log into work machines from here, so I can't test it right now.  But I believe ncurses is the route for that (http://linux.die.net/man/3/ncurses).

Comment: I was actually thinking in terms of Unix-based systems - but this helps for Windows.  Thanks!

Comment: I get a "`non-ISO-standard escape sequence, '\e'`" when using this with C11.

Answer (score 9):

```
#include <conio.h>
```

and use

```
clrscr()
```

Comment: Do note that this is not portable.

Comment: And it is not in c standard. Note that , OP mentioned Is there a "proper" way

Answer (score 5):

There is no C portable way to do this.  Although various cursor manipulation libraries like curses are relatively portable.  [conio.h](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h) is portable between OS/2 DOS and Windows, but not to *nix variants.

The entire notion of a "console" is a concept outside of the scope of standard C.

If you are looking for a pure Win32 API solution, There is no single call in the Windows console API to do this. One way is to [FillConsoleOutputCharacter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms682663(VS.85).aspx)  of a sufficiently large number of characters.  Or [WriteConsoleOutput](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms687404(VS.85).aspx) You can use [GetConsoleScreenBufferInfo](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms683171(VS.85).aspx)  to find out how many characters will be enough.

You can also create an entirely new Console Screen Buffer and make the current one.

Answer (score 4):

Windows:

`system("cls");`

Unix:

`system("clear");`

You could instead, insert newline chars until everything gets scrolled, take a look [here](http://www.cprogramming.com/faq/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1031963460&id=1043284385).

With that, you achieve portability easily.

Comment: The OP explicitly said this was NOT what he was looking for.

Comment: \n way immediately poses a next problem: what is min number of newlines has to be written to get **everything** scrolled out of terminal?

Comment: @PrematureOptimization `Forty quadvigiseptanovatriheptasexgesillion`, which we won't have CPUs capable of processing until we have a 2048-bit CPU with a bitchin bignum library. Sorry, you're out of luck. You're just gonna have to live with the fact that people who run their system using the side of the Empire State Building as a projection monitor with a fullscreen terminal running a 1pt font will get an ugly-looking "clear" effect. That's a rare edge case. Otherwise, ~100 lines should do the trick. (Xterm running its default font at fullscreen on a 1080p monitor is only 74 lines tall)

Comment: @Wilhelm This may not have been what the OP was looking for, but it was EXACTLY what I was looking for. Thanks.

Answer (score 3):

just type clrscr(); function in void main().

as example:

```
void main()
{
clrscr();
printf("Hello m fresher in programming c.");
getch();
}

clrscr();
```

function easy to clear screen.

Comment: `void main` is **very** bad. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9442121/what-was-wrong-with-void-main

Comment: Its not **very** bad as most compilers will correct it automatically. You are correct that it is wrong and shouldnt be used.

Comment: `test.c:(.text+0x31): undefined reference to 'clrscr' collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status`. With stdio.h and stdlib.h included. Not portable.

Answer (score 1):

In Windows I have made the mistake of using

```
system("clear")
```

but that is actually for Linux

The Windows type is

```
system("cls")
```

without `#include conio.h`

Comment: How many times do I have to tell everybody?! Don't use `system()`.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do it is by using `tput` or `terminfo` functions to obtain terminal properties and then insert newlines according to the dimensions..

Comment: Huh?! Assuming the terminfo call was successful, and the terminal type is a smart (not 'dumb' or 'tty') then you might as well use a terminfo (or termcap) clear screen instruction (clear / cl), rather than pushing multiple newlines, which can be slow on larger X-Window terminals, particularly across networks.

Answer (score -6):

This should work. Then just call cls(); whenever you want to clear the screen.

(using the method suggested before.)

```
#include <stdio.h>
void cls()
{
    int x;
    for ( x = 0; x < 10; x++ ) 
    {
        printf("\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n\n");
    }
}
```

Comment: For this kind of solution, a loop construct (`while` or `for`) would be a little more elegant. See for example: http://www.cprogramming.com/faq/cgi-bin/smartfaq.cgi?answer=1031963460&id=1043284385

Comment: "Yes I could have I guess. But why use a loop when I can copy-paste for the same effect?" Because copy'n'paste violates one of the most important rules in good programming: DRY - Don't repeat yourself

Comment: I have done as you suggested, and added a nice loop :)

Comment: That prints 160 newlines and leaves the cursor at the bottom of the screen. It's actually possible to have a window taller than 160 lines.

Comment: Seconding Keith Thompson, I get already 159 lines on an old, vertical full HD monitor. The moment I'm upgrading to 4k, there *will* be more than 160 lines... General point: **Never assume "oh, this will suffice in all cases". Cause it won't. Whenever you assume this, you are producing a bug that's just waiting to happen.** Always actually determine your need, or choose methods that always do the right thing. (Same with buffer lengths, string lengths, etc. pp.)