# Why wasn't void main() standardized as a valid signature for the main function?

Tags: c++, standards, program-entry-point, language-design, entry-point

Why has setting the entry point's return type to `void` in C++ always been discouraged, and was later removed by the standard and is prohibited by modern compilers? Why is it considered bad practice?

Now, as I understand C# and Java both allow the entry point's return type to be `void` i.e

```
static void main(String[] args) /* Java */
static void Main(string[] args) /* C# */
```

And C# and Java programmers do not consider it bad practice, they use it often in fact.

Other languages which are (only *intended* to be, I doubt C++ will be succeeded in this decade, at least) possible successors of C++ like the D Programming Language or Vala also allow a `void main()`. So as you can see, I doubt the C++ community removed it from the standard because it was too obscure or unpopular.

So my question is, Why did the C++ Community Remove `void main()`? What was wrong with it?

Comment: Different language designers make different decisions. Why does it matter?

Comment: @GregHewgill I understand that. But what were the factors & reasons that made C++ designers make the decision they did?

Comment: Straight from the horse's mouth :http://www2.research.att.com/~bs/bs_faq2.html#void-main :)

Comment: Actually, the question is wrong: given that a result from a program indicating at least success or failure is a Good Thing and was used in the context of where C was created (UNIX tools frequently use this indication) the question should be: why did the Java and C# communities remove the ability to indicate (and mandate) an indication of program success? This actually implicitly answers what's wrong with `void main()`: there is no result from a program. In addition `void main()` wasn't _removed_: it was never _added_.

Comment: I'd say using exceptions is the preferred way. If a program throws an exception that indicates a "classic" error state, then the built-in error handler should return the "classic" return-code equivalent value for you. Doing it manually is quite redundant. You still can use a function like exit(retcode) in Java, though. You can create your own  top level catch block to return codes and just use exit(...).

Answer (score 17, accepted):

The C++ standards committee likely chose to require `int main()` because of the large body of existing code that expected to use a `return` statement to return a specific exit code to the runtime system. It would be unreasonable to expect all existing code to change to use `exit()` instead, so `int main()` was made a requirement in the standard.

A language such as Java, when it was designed, did not have any body of existing code that it needed to remain compatible with. Therefore, the designers could choose `void main()` and require the use of `System.exit()` for non-zero exit codes.

So, the thing that would be "wrong" with choosing `void main()` for the C++ standard would be that it would break existing code that expected to use `return` and an exit code value from `main()`.

Comment: I see. So they chose `int main()` for compatibility with existing code. lol, I should have known... :D

Comment: I didn't attend the early C++ standards meetings but I doubt that the committee really choose anything: the use of a return value was part of C++ right from its start because it was meant to be essentially an extension of C. C essentially also used to have an `int` return (although typically implicitly declared: you could leave off `int` initially and the compiler would just assume that this is what you meant) to have a way of telling automatically if a program was successful. If the result of a program is `void` this doesn't give any indication whether it was successful.

Answer (score 12):

C++ has *never* permitted `void main()`, though some compilers might permit it either as an extension or just because they don't diagnose it.

Similarly C has never permitted `void main()` other than as an extension; the same 1989 standard that introduced the `void` keyword defined the two standard definitions for `main`: `int main(void)` and `int main(int argc, char *argv[])`.

Other languages permit it because, well, they're other languages.

There is no particular advantage in being able to write `void main()` rather than `int main()`.  You don't even need to explicitly return a value; falling off the end of `main` is equivalent to `return 0;` (in C++, and in C starting with C99).

Comment: +1 for the facts. However, while it has never been permitted, even Bjarne Stroustrup himself has written `void main`, namely in the second edition (and probably also in the first, I didn't check) of "The C++ Programming Language". It's just a meme thing, like many other arbitrary and often ungood conventions.

Comment: @Cheersandhth.-Alf: I just checked the second edition (9th printing, I think) of TC++PL, and didn't see any references to `void main()` -- though there is at least one occurrence of `main()` with an implicit `int` return type (the language no longer permits that). I checked all references to `main` from the index. Was it corrected in the edition I have, or did I miss something?

Comment: Well, like you now, Bjarne was a little skeptical about the claim that he'd done anything like that, back in 2006. See e.g. [http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/1fc435ef004677be](http://groups.google.com/group/comp.lang.c++/msg/1fc435ef004677be), where I answered "First example I found now at the end of section 7.3.2, page 233". I don't have that book available here and now, but I assume that my own ref was correct. :-)

Comment: Son of a gun, it's still there in the 9th printing of the second edition. It's also there in the 1st printing of the third edition: section 11.4, page 275. But it's mentioned in the [errata](http://www.stroustrup.com/3rd_printing2.html), so it must have been corrected in the 2nd printing (which came out after you mentioned it on comp.lang.c++).

Answer (score 9):

You generally want to know the exit status of your program. That's the reason why you have the `int main()` -- you return your exit status.

Answer (score 4):

It's wrong because this is not what the C++ Standard specifies as a legal `main`. Nobody cares about what the other languages specify. For C++ programs, only the C++ Standard is relevant, and it says `int`.

Comment: The question, in other words, is why does it say that?

Comment: @Soufiane: The question asks why it's not valid.#

Comment: _It's wrong because this is not what the C++ Standard specifies_ ... _only the C++ Standard is relevant_ . lol, from this I gather that 
`the C++ Standard == The Newest Divine Testament`

Comment: If you're writing a C++ program, then, well, yes.

Comment: " *For C++ programs, only the C++ Standard is relevant, and it says int.* ". -1 , because clearly the C standard is equally important to C++ programmers in practise.