# C++ contact card, re-running program trouble

Tags: c++

For my assignment, I have to make a customer card with some info required. I am able to run the program just fine, but when I re-run it with the "Do you wish to run again? (Y/N)", the first 2 questions appear on the same line and it messes up the program. Could anyone help me fix this issue?

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <iomanip>
int main()
{

char answer;


system("CLS");
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "***            W E L C O M E !            ***" << endl;
cout << "*** In this program you will be creating  ***" << endl;
cout << "***      a Customer Contact card!         ***" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
system("pause");

do

{

string name;
string city;
string address;
string state;
string phone_number;
string zip;




system("CLS");

cout << endl;
cout << "Enter the name of your contact : ";
getline(cin,name);
cout << "Enter your contact's phone number : ";
getline(cin,phone_number);
cout << "Enter your contact's address : ";
getline(cin,address);
cout << "Enter the city your contact lives in : ";
getline(cin,city);
cout << "Enter the state your contact lives in (Enter the abbreviation)  : ";
getline(cin,state);
cout << "Enter your contact's zip code : ";
cin >> zip;
system("pause");

system("CLS");

cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "***                                       ***" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "*** " << name <<  setw(41- name.length()) << "***" << endl;
cout << "*** " << address << setw(41- address.length()) << "***" << endl;
cout << "*** " << city << " " << state << " , " << zip << setw(30- city.length()) << "***" << endl;
cout << "*** " << state << setw(41- state.length()) << "***" << endl;
cout << "*** ";
cout<<"(";
for(int i = 0; i < 3; i++) {
cout << phone_number[i];
}
cout << ")";
for(int i = 3; i < 6; i++) {
cout << phone_number[i];
}
cout << "-";
for(int i = 6; i < 10; i++) {
cout << phone_number[i];
}
cout << setw(38- phone_number.length()) << "***" << endl;


cout << "*** " << zip << setw(41- zip.length()) << "***" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << "*********************************************" << endl;
cout << endl;
cout << "Do you want to create another contact card? (Y/N)" << endl;
cin >> answer;

}

while (answer == 'Y' || answer == 'y');


return 0;


}
```

Comment: `system("CLS")` makes me all sorts of sad. There are [better ways to do this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17335816/clear-screen-using-c) that don't involve running system calls.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are mixing `cin >>` and `getline(cin,`. So the newline was still stuck in `cin` by the time you wanted to read the first question's answer on the second run.

Stick to one or the other and this confusing behavior shouldn't present itself.

As mentioned in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/5740111/1460794): you could also add the following after `cin >> answer` to clear `cin` up to and including the newline:

```
cin.ignore(std::numeric_limits<std::streamsize>::max(),'\n');
```

Comment: I tried converting all the cin to getline(cin, but getline(cin, answer) isn't working.

Comment: True, you would have to change the type of `answer`. Perhaps the `ignore` alternative I've just referenced in the last edit would be easier at this point.

Comment: Could you show how it would be written in my circumstance? sorry, I'm terribly new to this stuff and this is a beginner course so I'm still pretty bad.

Comment: Just add the line exactly as written above. You might also need to add `#include <limits>` at the top.