# Simple menu in c

Tags: c, console, console-application

I am a new computer science student and I am currently working on a university project on super shop management system.

For that, I want a menu system. I tried using switch case.
It works but, for example, when I press `1` program goes to another function defined by me.

But main menu function still appears on the top.
I want a menu where i will press a number and program will proceed to a certain function clearing the previous commands I used.

Any help would be appreciated. Thank you.

(I tried using switch case. And I am newbie and don't know anything about file handling and that kind of stuff)

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<math.h>
#include<stdlib.h>


//User defined function declaration

int main_menu();
int products();
double payment();
int customer();

//User defined sub menus



//under products

int home_products();
int electronics();

int add_products();
int remove_products();
int products_quantity();

//Under payment

double billing();

//under customer menu()

int customer_inf();
int edit_customer();




int main ()
{
int input;

printf("                              Hello ADMIN\n                          SHIRONAMHIN Super Shop\n================================================================================");
printf("                              -Products\n                              -Payment/Billing\n                              -Customer information\n");
printf("\n");
printf(" Press One for Products \n Press two for Billing \n Press Three for Customer information \n Press 0 to terminate program");
scanf("\n%d", &input);
if(input==0)
{
    return 0;  //Program will be terminated if 0 is pressed
}
switch(input)
{
case 1:
    if(input==1)
    {
        products();
    }
    break;
case 2:
    if(input==2)
    {
        payment();
    }
    break;
case 3:
    if(input==3)
    {
        customer();
    }
    break;

default:
    printf("Enter a valid number");
    break;
}
 }


  int products()

  {
    int input;
printf("\n                              -Home products\n                              -Electronics\n\n Press any key rather than 1 and 2 two return to main menu");

scanf("%d", &input);

switch (input)
{
case 1:
    if(input == 1)
        home_products();
    break;

case 2:
    if(input == 2)
        electronics();
    break;

default:
    main();
    break;
}

   }

   int home_products()
     {
      int input;
         printf("Code yet to be written\n\n return to main menu by pressing 1 on the keyboard");
    scanf("%d", &input);
      if(input == 1)
       {
         return main();
     }


      }

   int electronics()
       {
      printf("Code yet to be written");
        }

      double payment()
      {

        return main();

      }

      int customer()
          {
     printf("Code yet to be written");

      return main();
          }
```

Comment: We can't help you with why your code is not working if you don't post your code here. If you can't get started on your assignment, ask your instructor for help.

Comment: Can you post the code that you've tried so far?

Comment: @JosephSible code added

Comment: You want to clear the previous screen, either by adding a lot of line return ( simple ), or use a terminal library to clear the window

Comment: possible duplicate http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-console-screen-in-c

Comment: Please Indent Your Code Properly.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You Can Take A Look At This [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/33450696/5473170). I Have Tested It On Windows.

Basically It Says

> A workaround tested on Windows(cmd.exe), Linux(Bash and zsh) and OS X(zsh):
>
> You Can Have A Function Like This
>
> ```
> void clrscr()
> {
>     system("cls||clear");
> }
> ```

Basically Issue With `system("cls")`(Works On Windows) is that it is not portable and same goes for `system("clear")`(Works On Linux).

Above Function Works On Both.

You Can Have It Like This

```
case 1:
    if(input==1)
    {
        clrscr();
        products();
    }
```

So If `input == 1`, first `clrscr()` will be called and console will be cleared and then `products()` will be called. You Can Do Same With all Other Function, do not forget to include the definition of the function `clrscr()` above.

Also I Highly Recommend You to take a look at This Question [How do you clear the console screen in C?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-console-screen-in-c) For more information on this topic.

Comment: Thank you so much. It helped.

Comment: @AdibHasib You Are Welcome , Please Also Read The Other Question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-console-screen-in-c

Comment: @AdibHasib And Also Send Your Regards To This Answer http://stackoverflow.com/a/33450696/5473170 , this is the one I Referred To.