# scanf is not waiting for an integer input

Tags: c, scanf, infinite-loop, turbo-c

```
printf("Enter an integer: ");
status = scanf("%d", &integer);

if (status == 0){
    do{
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &integer);
    }
    while (status == 0);
}
```

I'm trying to prevent a user from entering a data of type of character. However, after the prompt, "Please enter an integer: ", it doesn't wait for an input. Hence, it goes into an infinite loop whenever I enter a letter at the first prompt.  How do I fix this? Any heeelp will be greatly appreciated!

Comment: You’ll need to read the non-digit somehow.  The `”%d”` won’t read it ever. Or will see it, recognize it isn’t a digit and stop, leaving it for the next attempt.

Comment: @klutt, I also checked that already, but the error there was because scanf stores the carriage return (hitting enter after the prompt). I don't think it's applicable to this one because %d automatically skips white spaces.

Comment: Even if you fixed your loop, the code wouldn't detect a user entering something like `5x`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need clean the buffer first, you can use `fflush(stdin);` like this:

```
int integer, status=0;
if (status == 0)
{
    do
    {
        printf("\nPlease enter an integer: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &integer);
        fflush(stdin);
    }
    while (status == 0);
}
```

**It's not in standard C** using `fflush(stdin)` but you can clean the buffer in other ways.

You can build your own function to clean the buffer, like this:

```
void flushKeyBoard()
{
    int ch; //variable to read data into
    while((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
```

To clean the screen call this function:

```
void clrscr()
{
    system("@cls||clear");
}
```

**Final code:**

```
#include <stdio.h>

void clrscr()
{
    system("@cls||clear");
}
void flushKeyBoard()
{
    int ch; //variable to read data into
    while((ch = getc(stdin)) != EOF && ch != '\n');
}
int main()
{
    int integer, status=0;
    if (status == 0)
    {
        do
        {
            printf("\nPlease enter an integer: ");
            status = scanf("%d", &integer);
            flushKeyBoard();
            clrscr();
        }
        while (status==0);
    }
}
```

Comment: Hey, it works. But it prints "Please enter an integer" twice after entering the first incorrect data. Do you have any idea how to fix it?

Comment: `do{
        printf("Please enter an integer: ");
        status = scanf("%d", &integer);
    }` =>             `printf("Please enter an integer: ");
do{
        status = scanf("%d", &integer);
    }`

Comment: @LenovoGenovia I will edit my answer

Comment: Even though this works on many systems I think it is a very bad idea to teach people to use `fflush` on input streams. It is undefined behavior.

Comment: @klutt I did not say it was a good way, I write the flushKeyBoard()

Comment: Either you should remove that section completely or make it **abundantly** clear that it is potentially **very** dangerous. I would vote to remove it. Those who have a good use for that already knows.

Comment: @FábioMorais, I'm new  to C, and this will probably be annoying, but...
I'm getting an error saying "Function system should have a prototype." So I'm guessing I'm missing a header file?

Comment: @LenovoGenovia Just a friendly advice. Googling error messages is a thing programmers do every day. Get used to it.

Comment: @LenovoGenovia And another friendly advice. Stop using Turbo C. It's non-standard and was discontinued ages ago.

Comment: @klutt, I've heard that a lot, but our professor requires us to us Turbo C.

Comment: @LenovoGenovia You just need the #include <stdio.h>, maybe it's the clrscr() function, search for other functions to clean the screen. [Example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2347770/how-do-you-clear-the-console-screen-in-c)

Answer (score -2):

your %integer, should be declared int.
Like that:

```
int integer;

 printf("Please input an integer value: ");

 scanf("%d", &integer);
```

Comment: Yes, I did declare it as integer, I just wasn't able to show it on the post. And it's still not working.

Comment: This is not the issue. There are leftover characters in the input buffer from the previous attempt