# How do I delete the skipped part of the screen after I used "\33[2J\33[H" many times?

Tags: c++, windows, io, stdout

I'm writing a terminal game for Windows, and the refresh was quite slow so I asked [`here`](https://codereview.stackexchange.com/questions/277885/game-loop-using-future-wait-for-to-check-for-input) for help.

```
std::cout << "\33[2J\33[H"; // They told me to write this...
system("cls") // ...instead of this
```

But sending that ASCII escape sequence just makes the terminal *"scroll"*, without deleting anything.

---

Lets say I really want to delete the old frames sometimes: how should I do it?

---

Just to make an example, they told me that...

```
std::cout << '\n'; // This...
std::cout << std::endl; // ...was faster than this
```

Then I asked what was missing to `\n` to become equivalent to `std::endl`, and they told me `std::flush`.

So my question is: **what is missing to `\33[2J\33[H` to be equivalent to `system("cls")`?**

Comment: Since you're targeting Windows, I suggest you use the Windows-specific [console functions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/console/console-functions), rather than trying to keep it portable using common escape sequences and `std::cout`.

Comment: I liked the idea to make it portable, but Windows has a completely different way to get characters, so conio.h is only compatible with Windows, and what's compatible with Linux/MacOS isn't compatible with Windows. So, since it can't be cross-platform unless I write an hell of #ifdef, I'll probably use system("cls"). I was just curious to know if under the hood cls was using that escape sequence.

Comment: Even when targeting only Windows, *please* don't use `system("cls")`. It adds a *lot* of overhead. Use the console functions I linked to earlier. See e.g. the second code snippet in [this old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/42500322/440558). Or [this other old answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/6487534/440558).

Comment: Thank you, I tried the first one and it works properly. I've never messed up with the Windows API so this was very useful to me.

Comment: Under the hood, `cls` is using the WinAPI directly and not generating ANSI escape sequences.