# How do I clear the console in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, macos, cocoa, console, console-application

I'm  making a console-based application in Objective-C which relies on being able to **clear the console** periodically. How can this be done? All I've seen on SO and Google were ways to have the developer clear the console with X-Code, but that will *not* do.

One solution I found on Yahoo! Answers told me to do the following, but it does not run due to being unable to find a file:

```
NSTask *task;
task = [[NSTask alloc]init];
[task setLaunchPath: @"/bin/bash"];

NSArray *arguments;
arguments = [NSArray arrayWithObjects: @"clear", nil];
[task setArguments: arguments];

[task launch];
[task waitUntilExit];
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

**Try using :**

```
system( "clear" );
```

**Important headers :**

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

---

***Hint :*** Objective-C is still C, right?

---

**UPDATE :**

---

*In case of a **"TERM environment variable not set."** error :*

1) Run the program, directly from your terminal (or just ignore the error while testing it in Xcode; it's supposed to run in a normal terminal anyway, huh?)

2) Set the TERM variable in your Scheme's settings.
To what? Just run this in your terminal to see what "TERM" should be :

```
DrKameleons-MacBook-Pro:Documents drkameleon$ echo $TERM
xterm-256color
```

---

[image]

Comment: Objective-C is still C, but I prefer "native-feeling" solutions :)

Comment: @houbysoft I do too; definitely. But honestly isn't using `NSTask` too much for something as simple as an `system("clear")`? The Cocoa way may at times be unnecessarily verbose... :-)

Comment: All this does is print "TERM environment variable not set." and continue with the program

Comment: @Supuhstar *"The error message you're seeing says that the TERM environment variable isn't set, probably because you're trying to launch your program from within Xcode."* -- http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8470184/what-does-term-environment-variable-not-set-mean

Comment: Thanks for the diagnosis, but what's the fix?

Comment: Seems descriptive and helpful, but I've scoured Xcode's preferences four times over and didn't see so much as a mention of a scheme, much less its settings.

Comment: In the "Executables" group, select the executable for your program and Get Info.  In there, there's a place to set environment variables when running from Xcode.

Comment: I've added your code to mine, added a TERM variable to Xcode's project settings with the same value given by `echo $TERM` in the Terminal (in my case, `xterm-color`), and ran it. It still tells me `TERM environment variable not set`

Comment: Then you must have done it incorrectly, I'm afraid. I just tested with Xcode 3.2.6, with the code from my answer. In my case, it doesn't clear Xcode's console window, because that's not a real terminal, but it printed the appropriate escape sequence and didn't error out. You're not going to find any solution which clears the Xcode console window, I don't think, because it would require Xcode to handle that and I doubt Xcode is coded to. In a Terminal window, my test worked completely.

Answer (score 4):

The way to do this without spawning a subprocess is to use ncurses.

```
#include <curses.h>
#include <term.h>
#include <unistd.h>

int main(void)
{
    setupterm(NULL, STDOUT_FILENO, NULL);
    tputs(clear_screen, lines ? lines : 1, putchar);
}
```

Compile with `-lncurses`.

The `setupterm()` call only needs to be done once.  After that, use the `tputs()` call to clear the screen.

Comment: Looks promising, but I can't figure out how to add command-line options for compiling with XCode

Comment: Add "-lncurses" to the Other Linker Flags (OTHER_LDFLAGS) build setting for the target.

Comment: `TERM environment variable not set.

Debugger stopped.
Program exited with status value:1`

Comment: @Supuhstar: set an environment variable `TERM` in the environment section of the Arguments tab in the scheme for running your application.  The Apple terminal app uses `xterm-256color` as its value

Answer (score 3):

Why `/bin/bash`?

Just do:

```
NSTask *task = [NSTask launchedTaskWithLaunchPath:@"/usr/bin/clear" arguments:[NSArray array]];
```

Alternatively, using the C way:

```
#include <stdlib.h>

...
system("/usr/bin/clear");
...
```

Comment: The first one does nothing at all, and the second one just prints "TERM environment variable not set." and continue with the program.

Answer (score 1):

You can use apple script

```
tell application "Console"
    activate
    tell application "System Events"
        keystroke "k" using command down
    end tell
end tell
```

Use NSAppleScript class for executing applescript from obj-C program.

```
NSAppleScript *lClearDisplay = [[NSAppleScript alloc] initWithSource:@"tell application \"Console\"\n \
                                activate\n \
                                tell application \"System Events\"\n \
                                keystroke \"k\" using command down\n \
                                end tell\n \
                                    end tell "];
NSDictionary *errorInfo;
[lClearDisplay executeAndReturnError:&errorInfo];
```

**NOTE:**
If Apple changes or removes ⌘k as the key command for clear display, that will break script.

Comment: How do I use this with an Obj-C program?

Comment: Compile error: `'errorInfo' undeclared (first use in this function)`

Comment: Does nothing to the console. Sorry :/

Comment: This applescript is for console application not for xcode console and its working fine for me. open applescript editor and run.

Comment: Command-K *deletes* the scrollback buffer.  `clear` clears it, but leaves the scrollback buffer intact.