# node.js: Rewind and truncate console output?

Tags: node.js, console, terminal

I have a daemon script that clears/outputs to stdout every X seconds, like this:

```
function clearTerminal(){
    process.stdout.write('\u001B[2J\u001B[0;0f');
}

function printNum(){
    var rand = Math.floor(Math.random() * 10) + 2;
    console.log(rand);
}

function refreshTerminal(){
    clearTerminal();
    printNum();
}

refreshTerminal();
var interval = setInterval(refreshTerminal, 1000);
```

This works, but the daemon's output history is viewable by scrolling up after the daemon terminates.  I'd like to rewind and truncate stdout, as described here:

[Clearing output of a terminal program Linux C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348563/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-linux-c-c)

+1 if there's already a module out there for this, thanks!

Comment: What about just calling `clear`?

Comment: That's what the clearTerminal function does in my example.