# Clearing a terminal similar to man page using C

Tags: c, linux, manpage

I want to read a text file and display it. But I need to print it on terminal, similar to the man page (linux). That is, when scrolled up, it shouldn't go beyond the first line and scrolling down shouldn't go beyond the last line. I have to program it only in C. I shouldn't use any tools. My current coding for clearing a terminal alone is,

```
#include<stdio.h>

main()
{
printf("\033[2J");
printf("\033[0;0f");
FILE *ffp;
char c;

ffp=fopen("help.txt","r");
while((c=getc(ffp))!=EOF)
    printf("%c",c);
}
```

Kindly guide me. Thanks in advance.

UPDATED:

```
main()
{
FILE *ffp;
char c;


ffp=fopen("help.txt","r");

FILE *less = popen("less", "w");
while ((c = getc(ffp)) != EOF) {
  fputc(c, less);
}
}
```

Comment: Am I the only who thinks about `ncurses`?

Comment: nope, you are not alone!

Comment: @maverik Yes. But it's a pre-defined tool. I need to get it programmed, as I cleared the terminal using a C code.

Comment: Is this some kind of homework ? In real life you'd use `less` (or whatever is set in the `PAGER` environment variable). No C is ever required here (and it goes against the UNIX spirit to use C for this task).

Comment: @AlexandreC. Yes. It's a part of my project. I'll try PAGER enironment variable. Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
FILE *less = popen("less", "w");
while ((c = getc(ffp)) != EOF) {
  fputc(c, less);
}
```

`more` and `less` are the programs that implement scrolling through a file or pipe a screenful at a time.

Comment: Thank you. What header file should I use for less? I'm getting an undeclared variable error.

Comment: I've added the declaration. Couldn't you look in the man page for `popen()`?

Comment: Thanks and sorry. But the file is not getting displayed. I have updated my code in question.

Comment: Is the `less` program in your `$PATH`?

Comment: If I use 'more' it displays the file. But it makes no difference. It still can be scrolled up to see the remaining part of the terminal!

Comment: That's just the way terminal emulator scrollback buffers work.

Comment: I read that, there are certain tools for creating man page, like Troff and Groff. Is that the only way then? Programming in C seems impossible.

Comment: This has nothing to do with the tools used for creating man pages. `man` just uses $PAGER to display the file.

Answer (score 1):

try something like this,,

```
#include <stdio.h>

int
main ()
{
    fputs("output1\n",stdout);
    fputs("output2\n",stdout);
    fputs("\033[A\033[2K\033[A\033[2K",stdout);
    rewind(stdout);
    ftruncate(1,0); /* you probably want this as well */
    fputs("output3\n",stdout);
    fputs("output4\n",stdout);
    return 0;
}
```

**SOURCE:**
[Clearing output of a terminal program Linux C/C++](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1348563/clearing-output-of-a-terminal-program-linux-c-c)

Comment: I already viewed that answer. It only clears the previous two lines. My coding clears even an entire screen!

Comment: Thanks. But clearing isn't a matter, which I can already do using my code. I want it similar to a man page. Please read my question again.