# Why I can't overwrite the current line in command line?

Tags: python, python-3.x

I was trying to over write a line
I want to overwrite the pervious lines so it will appear like a different menu, but it doesn't seem to work with input function, how do I overwrite this?

```
def menu():

    sys.stdout.write("Menu 1")
    x = input("Enter: ")

    sys.stdout.write('\r other different data')
    sys.stdout.flush()


menu()
```

Comment: Not sure if python supports ANSI escape codes, but take a look at http://stackoverflow.com/a/1348624/1709894

Comment: input uses the standard in and waits for newline before returning data. This means that you are already on a new line

Comment: **this is about what is displaying the output not your code.**  IDLE, the default python ide does not support this and is not even simple to work around.  If you run it with terminal/command line it should work.

Comment: After `x = input("Enter: ")` is executed, the user enters their data, and presses `<enter>,` so - the script would be on a new line.